# Is it possible Select and Autocopy in Mac

Tags: software-recommendation, finder, copy-paste, text-input

I would like autocopy for every text that I select to avoid to do several CMD+C.

Is there any way or application to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know of any software that does that at a system level and apparently, neither do [these guys at SuperUser](https://superuser.com/q/87470/3349). ;)

The reason why there’s no extension that does this for Safari yet is because the API for Extensions on Safari doesn’t support Clipboard mechanism at this time.

Comment: Ah... It seems is not possible u_u

Answer (score 0):

You can get this for Terminal by using [iTerm](http://iterm.sourceforge.net/) instead

Comment: Thanks, i'll try it, but I'm searching for something that does a system level